# White box occurring when dragging objects in electron

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am developing an application using ReactJS, NodeJS and electron. I am testing it on a raspberry pi 4b running ubuntu desktop.

I have implemented a drag and drop feature of certain components using event listeners and the css transform translate attributes to calculate the real time position change.

Whenever I drag an object, a white box appears in the background of the object. Does anybody know why this is happening

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you read the guides on [ask] good questions and how to create a [mcve]. People won't be able to help you without giving more information about your code and your problem.